# Directly prove that$\ (S')' \subset S'$

Tags: real-analysis

Let$\ S \subset \mathbb R^n$. Directly prove that$\ (S')' \subset S'$

I know that the derived set of$\ S$ is the set of all the limit ponts of$\ S$, that is, $\ S'$

I don't exactly know how to approach this problem, I tried to prove it by contradiction, but don't know if that's the right way.

I tried supposing that$\ x$ is not an element of$\ S$, so$\ x$ is no an accumulation point of$\ S$ so$\ \exists p$ such that

$\ B_x(P) \cap S = ∅$.

The fact that$\ x$ must be a point of$\ S'$ implies that

$\ B_x(P) \cap S' \neq ∅$

Don't know where to go from here.

Comment: What does your notation $S'$ mean?  It is likely proved just using the definition.

Comment: The derived set, I just made an edit on the post.

Comment: How has derived to set been defined for you? In terms of open neighborhoods? In terms of sequence limits? In terms of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$? Some other way?  If you actually show us what you tried, it would make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I made the corresponding edits

Comment: Youre asking when the accumulation points of the accumulation points of a set is a proper subset of the original set?  Never.  You cant prove that because it isnt true.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum: Many texts use $\subset$ to mean "is a subset of," and $\subsetneq$ to mean "is a proper subset of." I personally prefer the convention that $\subset$ indicates proper subsets and $\subseteq$ indicates subsets, but I don't run the world. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's the definition I'd use. Let me know if it's not close enough to yours.

> $x \in S'$ if and only if every open ball $B$ containing $x$ contains
>   another point $y$ distinct from $x$.

So just use your standard set inclusion argument.

Let $x \in (S')'$ then every open ball containing $x$ contains another distinct point of $S'$. Fix an open ball $x \in B$ then there is a $y \in S'\cap B$ with $y\neq x$

Then since $y \in S'$ and $y \in B$ there is another point $z \in S$ with $z\neq y$

Now if $z\neq x$ we are done.

To handle the it more eloquently instead of taking $y \in B$ take a new ball $B'$ around $y$ with radius small enough so that $B' \subsetneq B$ and $x \not\in B'$ (this is up to you).

Comment: If you add $x\not\in B'$, then $x\not=z$ becomes easier.

Comment: @MichaelBurr ah yes I apparently forgot to type that part :) I've edited that in now

Comment: And how can one be sure that$\ z \neq x$ ?

Comment: @DavidTomahak You need to pick a small enough radius for $B'$ around $y$ so that both $B' \subsetneq B$ and $x \not\in B'$ then since $z \in B'$ you'd have $z \neq x$. This is easier to do if you center $B$ at $x$ and specify some radius $\epsilon>0$. Then center $B'$ at $y$ and find the small enough radius.

Comment: Okay, I'll  give it a shot, thanks

Comment: Can't seem to figure out the radius that works, is$\ s = 1/2(r - ||x-y||)$ ok? Where r is the radius of the fixed ball$\ B$ and$\ s$ is the new radius I'm trying to give to the$\ B'$ ball

Answer (score 1):

Here are two other approaches you can take.

I will use the same definition of derived set as the prior answer. Put into more precise terms:

> Given $A\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ and $x\in\Bbb R^n,$ we say that $x\in A'$ if and only if for all $\rho>0$ and all $z\in\Bbb R^n$ with $\lVert x-z\rVert<\rho$ the set $B_z(\rho)$ contains some $y\in A$ with $x\neq y.$ Put another way, the elements of $A'$ are precisely the points $x$ such that, for all $\rho>0$ and $z\in\Bbb R^n,$ we have $$x\in B_z(\rho)\implies\bigl\{y\in B_z(\rho)\cap A:x\neq y\bigr\}\neq\emptyset.$$

---

***First Approach***: The key here is to use the following

> **Lemma**: Given a set $S\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ and a point $x\in\Bbb R^n,$ we have that $x\in S'$ if and only if every open ball containing $x$ contains infinitely-many points of $S.$
>
> **Proof**: Clearly, the latter implies the former, since having infinitely-many points of $S$ in the ball entails that there is a point $y$ of $S$ in the ball that is distinct from $x.$ (In fact, there will be *infinitely-many* such points $y,$ but that's a side note.)
>
> To prove that the former implies the latter, we proceed by contrapositive. Assume that, for some $\rho_0>0$ and some $z\in\Bbb R^n,$ the ball $B:=B_z(\rho_0)$ contains only finitely-many points of $S.$ If $\{y\in B\cap S:x\neq y\}=\emptyset,$ then we're done by definition, so suppose not. Since $\{y\in B\cap S:x\neq y\}\neq\emptyset,$ and since it is a subset of the finite set $B\cap S,$ then it is likewise finite. Thus, we have $$\{y\in B\cap S:x\neq y\}=\{y_1,...,y_m\}$$ for some positive integer $m.$ For each integer $j$ with $1\le j\le m,$ we have $y_j\neq x,$ so $\rho_j:=\lVert x-y_j\rVert>0.$ Since $x\in B=B_z(\rho_0),$ then $\lVert x-z\rVert<\rho_0,$ so $\rho_{m+1}:=\rho_0-\lVert x-z\rVert>0.$ Let $$\rho:=\min\{\rho_1,...,\rho_m,\rho_{m+1}\}.$$
>
> Given any $v\in B_x(\rho),$ we have $$\lVert v-z\rVert\le\lVert v-x\rVert+\lVert x-z\rVert<\rho+\lVert x-z\rVert\le\rho_{m+1}+\lVert x-z\rVert=\rho_0,$$ so $v\in B.$ Thus, $B_x(\rho)\subseteq B,$ so $$\bigl\{y\in B_x(\rho)\cap S:x\neq y\bigr\}\subseteq\{y\in B\cap S:x\neq y\}=\{y_1,...,y_m\}.$$ Since $\rho\le\rho_j$ for $1\le j\le m,$ then $B_x(\rho)\cap\{y_1,...,y_m\}=\emptyset,$ so $\bigl\{y\in B_x(\rho)\cap S:x\neq y\bigr\}=\emptyset,$ and so $x\notin S',$ finishing our proof by contrapositive. $\Box$

Now we can show that $(S')'\subseteq S'$ directly, as follows:

> Take any $x\in(S')',$ and take any $\rho>0$ and $z\in\Bbb R^n$ such that $x\in B:=B_z(\rho).$ By definition of $A'$ (with $A=S'$), $B$ contains a point $y$ of $S'$ such that $x\neq y.$ Since $y\in S'$ and $B$ is an open ball containing $y,$ then by the Lemma, $B$ contains infinitely-many points of $S.$ Thus, $B$ contains a point $v$ of $S$ such that $x\neq v.$ Since $B$ was an arbitrary open ball containing $x,$ then by definition, $x\in S'.$ Since $x$ was an arbitrary point of $(S')',$ then $(S')'\subseteq S',$ as desired. $\Box$

---

***Second Approach***: Here we use the notion of an "open set," defined as follows:

> We say that a set $U\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ is open iff for all $x\in U,$ there exists some $\rho>0$ such that $B_x(\rho)\subseteq U.$

One can prove the following three facts, which I leave to you.

1. If $B\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ is an open ball, then $B$ is an open set.
2. If $x\in\Bbb R^n,$ then $\Bbb R^n\setminus\{x\}$ is an open set.
3. If $U$ and $V$ are open sets, then $U\cap V$ is an open set.

Now, the key is the following

> **Lemma**: Given a set $S\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ and a point $x\in\Bbb R^n,$ we have that $x\in S'$ if and only if every open set containing $x$ contains a point $y$ of $S$ such that $x\neq y.$
>
> **Proof**: Since open balls are open sets by Fact 1, then the latter clearly implies the former.
>
> Now, suppose that $x\in S',$ and let $U$ be any open set such that $x\in U.$ By definition of open set, there is some $\rho>0$ such that $B_x(\rho)\subseteq U.$ Since $B:=B_x(\rho)$ is an open ball containing $x$ and since $x\in S',$ then there is some $y\in B\cap S$ such that $x\neq y.$ Since $y\in B$ and $B\subseteq U,$ then $y\in U,$ and since $y\in S$ and $x\neq y,$ then we're done. $\Box$

Now, we can prove the desired result as follows:

> Take any $x\in(S')',$ and take any open set $U\subseteq R^n$ such that $x\in U.$ As in the prior approach, we need only prove that $x\in S'.$
>
> By the Lemma, $U$ contains a point $y$ of $S'$ such that $x\neq y.$ Letting $V:=\Bbb R^n\setminus\{x\},$ we have by Fact 2 that $V$ is an open set, and since $x\neq y,$ then $y\in V.$ Since $y\in U,$ as well, then by Fact 3, $U\cap V$ is an open set containing $y.$ Thus, since $y\in S',$ then by the Lemma, $U\cap V$ contains a point $z$ of $S$ such that $z\neq y.$ Since $z\in V,$ then by definition of $V$ we have $x\neq z.$ Since $z\in U$ and $z\in S,$ and since $U$ was an arbitrary open set containing $x,$ then by the Lemma, $x\in S',$ as desired. $\Box$

Comment: Thank you for your awesome advice, your second approach was actually pretty useful